# Differences between Mac Star Wars old Republic and online version

Tags: macos, star-wars-kotor

I purchased SWTOR from the Apple AppStore and don't have an option to play online.  Is there an online version?  Will it work with the Mac?

What are my options to make my Mac version work online?  I have Bootcamp installed, and accidentally purchased the wrong version

Comment: What? The Old Republic is an MMO – Massively Multiplayer Online game. There is no version that is *not* online.

Comment: Also, I can't find The Old Republic in the AppStore. Do you mean Knights of the Old Republic? That's a completely different game.

Comment: @svick Yes I suppose there are two versions, I have the app store one called Knights of the Old Republic.  Hmm this is confusing to have two similar games with similar names, and completely different features.

Comment: TOR can be viewed as a sort of sequel to KOTOR, but they are very separate games!  Voted to close since this was just confusion :P

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, KOTOR is an absolutely fantastic game. TOR is...somewhat less so, from what I hear. You bought the better game :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game you purchased for the Mac was [**Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic), a single player RPG based on the D20 system, developed by Bioware and released *in 2003*. (2004 for Mac OS X). It's a *great* game. What it *isn't* however, is [**Star Wars: The Old Republic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic), a Massively Multiplayer Online RPG developed by Bioware, and released *in 2011*.

**The Old Republic** is something of a 'sequel' to the two ***Knights of* the Old Republic** games, taking place in roughly the same setting several years later, and using many of the same settings. However, unlike the two previous games, it is not based on the D&D D20 ruleset, and it is an MMO, not a single player game. Furthermore, unlike **KOTOR**, **The Old Republic** is only available for Windows. There is no Mac version, and thus, you won't see it on the app store.

Luckily for you, this mistake won't cost you any more money than you've already spent. **The Old Republic** is now free-to-play, and can be downloaded directly from [the games website.](http://www.swtor.com)

Comment: The Old Republic is not free to play, at least not yet (that's supposed to come “this fall”). Although there is a time-unlimited trial for up to level 15 (out of 50).